# Number of decimal digits in C

Tags: c, floating-point

I like to change the number of decimal digits showed whenever I use a float number in C. Does it have something to do with the `FLT_DIG` value defined in `float.h`? If so, how could I change that from 6 to 10?

I'm getting a number like `0.000000` while the actual value is `0.0000003455`.

Comment: Are you talking about what your debugger shows you? Or is it about what some output of your program presents?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two separate issues here: The precision of the floating point number stored, which is determined by using `float` vs `double` and then there's the precision of the number being printed as such:

```
float foo = 0.0123456789;
printf("%.4f\n", foo);  // This will print 0.0123 (4 digits).

double bar = 0.012345678912345;
printf("%.10lf\n", bar);  // This will print 0.0123456789
```

Comment: Absolutely correct.  Both "float" (and "double") can *store* the value "0.0000003455", but you need to specify "%.10xx" in order to *print* it.  Great response :)!

Comment: Technically neither `float` nor `double` can store the value 0.0000003455, although they both can store something close enough.

Comment: @paulsm4 You really need to take a crash course about floating-point representation instead of trolling around on SO and downvoting here and there. +1 for Pascal Cuoq.

Answer (score 0):

I experimented this problem and I found out that you cannot have great precision with float they are really bad .But if you use double it would give you the right answer. just mention %.10lf for precision upto 10 decimal points

Answer (score -1):

You're running out of precision. Floats don't have great precision, if you want more decimal places, use the `double` data type.

Also, it seems that you're using `printf()` & co. to display the numbers - if you ever decide to use `double`s instead of `float`s, don't forget to change the format specifiers from `%f` to `%lf` - that's for a double.

Comment: `%f` by itself is already for `double`. According to C99's 7.19.16. Besides, a `double` is not needed to represent `0.0000003455` closely. Single-precision gives you 0x1.72fa52p-22 or approximately 3.455000126e-07.

Comment: You're only 1/2 correct :) If you tried this example, you'd see that it would print "0.0" for *both* floats and doubles!  You need to change the "printf" decimal precision.

Comment: @paulsm4 And now you can revoke your unjust downvote. I was not talking about how floating-point numbers are displayed (apart from the good advice for OP) - it's the users failure if he doesn't know about precision and witdh specifiers. Also note that downvotes should indicate **technical inaccuracies only,** of which this answer doesn't even have a single one.

Comment: "downvotes should indicate technical inaccuracies only, of which this answer doesn't even have a single one." Errm, what do you call "if you ever decide to use doubles instead of floats, don't forget to change the format specifiers from %f to %lf - that's for a double."? Since the format is for `printf` and not for `scanf`, that is a technical inaccuracy. Now, for floating point conversions (in `(f)printf`), the `l` length modifier has no effect per the standard, so it doesn't harm to write `%lf` for `double`s, but it's not necessary.

Comment: @DanielFischer 1. Nobody is talking about `scanf()` here. The discussion is about `printf()`. 2. The format specifiers are the same for both functions. 3. the `%f` format specifier is for `float`s, the `%lf` is for `double`s, and intermixing them is **undefined behavior.**

Comment: Right, we're not talking about `scanf`, where there is a difference between `%f` (for `float`s) and `%lf` (for `double`s), we're talking about `printf` **where both are completely equivalent**. Read the specifications in the standard, 7.19.6.1 in C99, 7.21.6.1 in C11 for `fprintf`, the `printf` specification says it's equivalent to `fprintf(stdout, format_and_other_args)`.

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm heading to reading the standard immediately.

Comment: First, this answer is flat wrong. Changing from float to double does not change how the value .0000003455 (converted to float or double) is printed with the default “%.f” specification, which is apparently what the questioner did. The statement “You're running out of precision” is false. Second, as explained previously, changing “%f” to “%lf” in an fprintf specification does nothing. Third, what is the basis for claiming downvotes should be based on technical inaccuracies only? An answer that is technically correct (unlike this one) but unclear or otherwise not useful deserves to be downvoted.

Answer (score -1):

@kosmoplan - thank you for a good question!

@epsalon - thank you for a good response.  My first thought, too, was "float" vs. "double".  I was mistaken.  You hit it on the head by realizing it was actually a "printf/format" issue.  Good job!

Finally, to put to rest some lingering peripheral controversy:

```
/*
 SAMPLE OUTPUT:
  a=0.000000, x=0.012346, y=0.012346
  a=0.0000003455, x=0.0123456791, y=0.0123456789
 */
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  float  x = 0.0123456789, a = 0.0000003455;
  double y = 0.0123456789;
  printf ("a=%f, x=%f, y=%lf\n", a, x, y);
  printf ("a=%.10f, x=%.10f, y=%.10lf\n", a, x, y);
  return 0;
}
```